Accessibility: Font enlargement does not work
I have a React app. On IOS Safari and IOS Chrome Font enlargement works without problems. On Android work on Firefox, but Chrome doesn't work. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?
I tried to fix this problem using font-size-adjust as written in another thread, but it didn't help.
